# How to generate Hexanacci numbers in java?

Tags: java, performance, biginteger

I am trying to generate the hexanacci series in java using BigInteger.

The series: 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 63, 125, 248, 492, 976, 1936, 3840, 7617, 15109, 29970, 59448, 117920, 233904, 463968, 920319, 1825529, 3621088, 7182728, 14247536, 28261168, 56058368 ...

Here is my code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

/**
 *
 * @author Tushar
 */
public class Hexanacci {

    static int result = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dest = 33;
        System.out.println(calc(BigInteger.valueOf(dest)));
    }

    public static BigInteger calc(BigInteger n) {
        if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {

            return BigInteger.ONE;

        } else if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 0) {

            return calc(BigInteger.ZERO);

        } else if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(2)) == 0) {


            return calc(BigInteger.valueOf(0))
                    .add(calc(BigInteger.valueOf(1)));


        } else if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(3)) == 0) {


            return calc(BigInteger.valueOf(0))
                    .add(calc(BigInteger.valueOf(1)))
                    .add(calc(BigInteger.valueOf(2)));


        } else if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(4)) == 0) {


            return calc(BigInteger.valueOf(0))
                    .add(calc(BigInteger.valueOf(1)))
                    .add(calc(BigInteger.valueOf(2)))
                    .add(calc(BigInteger.valueOf(3)));


        } else if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(5)) == 0) {


            return calc(BigInteger.ZERO)
                    .add(calc(BigInteger.ONE))
                    .add(calc(BigInteger.valueOf(2)))
                    .add(calc(BigInteger.valueOf(3)))
                    .add(calc(BigInteger.valueOf(4)));


        } else {


            return calc(n.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1)))
                    .add(calc(n.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(2))))
                    .add(calc(n.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(3))))
                    .add(calc(n.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(4))))
                    .add(calc(n.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(5))))
                    .add(calc(n.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(6))));


        }
    }
}
```

This program is running fine when dest is small. But if I increase the value of dest it gets hanged. For example when dist is 33 it takes almost 3 minutes to calculate the result:

```
3414621024
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 minutes 4 seconds)
```

Can anyone please tell me is it a right approach or not?

Comment: Calc calls itself in worst-case-scenario 6 times recursively, thats O(n^6).

Comment: Possible solution to that problem: memoization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is an easy way to improve the code and speed the operation up. Create a `Map<BigInteger, BigInteger>` to store the intermediate results. Something like,

```
static Map<BigInteger, BigInteger> memo = new HashMap<>();
static {
    int[] initial = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8 };
    for (int i = 0; i < initial.length; i++) {
        memo.put(BigInteger.valueOf(i), BigInteger.valueOf(initial[i]));
    }
}

public static BigInteger calc(BigInteger n) {
    if (memo.containsKey(n)) {
        return memo.get(n);
    }
    BigInteger orig = n, v = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        n = n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        v = v.add(calc(n));
    }
    memo.put(orig, v);
    return v;
}
```

Which returns the thirty-third term almost instantly.

Comment: really awesome.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to generate the hexanacci series

To generate the series up to `count`, you could just calculate the *moving sum*, no need for recursion.

```
// Pseudo code:

int count = 80;
mySeries = vector<BigInteger>;

preallocate mySeries to size 'count' (or 'add' items in the loop)
prefill mySeries with 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32

for (int i = 8; i < count; i++) {

                  // avoid multiplication by 2, unless BigInteger supports '<< 1'
    mySeries[i] = mySeries[i-1] + mySeries[i-1] - mySeries[i-7];
}
```

Results should be instant.